# Install Ubuntu flavors in Ubuntu 14.04 without changing the startup/login screens?

Tags: login-screen, plymouth

I recently installed the community's customized Linux desktops on another machine, such as KDE and LXDE, but I also noticed my boot-up screen and startup screen changed.

Is there any way I can install all of the community's customized desktops that come with the other versions of Ubuntu, like Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME, etc. and still keep the boot-up splash screen and the login landing screen as is?

If possible, provide a simple terminal command to do so.

Comment: You can use `update-alternatives` to set the splash screen and greeter back to the one that you want. There are a lot of questions in the site about how to do this. Also, you may find that the various desktops have some incompatibilities when installed together. There are also a lot of existing questions on that issue. You might want to use separate partitions for different flavors or at least make a new install where you can experiment with multiple desktops without blowing up your main install.

Comment: @chaskes - I agree with most of your information, but, the various desktops should be completely compatible with each other. If you have problems other then minor cosmetic issues or crowded menus, file a bug report .